# Adding and removing markers in openlayers on Drupal after page-load

Tags: drupal, openlayers

I have to change the data set displayed on a map according to selections on the page and I would like to do this by creating several marker layers then switching between them based on user input.
For some reason I cannot add a layer after the map has been rendered on the page, seems like it shouldn't be that hard I think I may have the syntax wrong since the way Drupal sets up the map is different from straight forward openlayers.
Can I not get the map object like

var map = Drupal.settings.openlayers.maps["openlayers-map-auto-id-0"];

then add and remove marker layers from it? maybe there's another way of getting it?

Any help appreciated, 
- Chris

Answer (score 2):

The Drupal OpenLayers module only stores *settings* in `Drupal.settings.openlayers.maps`.

What you need is something like this:

```
var ol = $('#openlayers-map-auto-id-0').data('openlayers');
var max_extent = ol.openlayers.getMaxExtent(); // Or some other OpenLayers method...
...
```

The actual OpenLayers instance (as well as a copy of the map-specific settings) are stored with jQuery's `.data()` method. When you call `$('#map-id').data('openlayers')` you'll get back an object with `map` and `openlayers` members that correspond to the map settings and the actual OL object instance, respectively.

You might want to consider writing an OL behavior to handle your use case -- check out the default behaviors provided by the Drupal OpenLayers module to get a sense of how this works.